# Is there a way to upload files to the Amazon S3 from SFTP

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My idea is this: I have an SFTP host with data on it and I want to create a file in S3 from this data, but to save network resources I don't want to download all of this data to a system first to upload again. So my question is: is it possible to transfer the data directly to the s3 without first downloading it? (preferably with the Amazon S3 Java SDK)